# How do I change emails from: address on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, email, php

Emails are now sent from www@hostname, but I want them to be sent from webmaster@my-domain.com

My developer said it should be in `php.ini` but I figured out this is true only for Win32 systems.

How do I make this change in FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE-p3?

Comment: What mailserver do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the default mailserver (sendmail), you should add the -f argument to the sendmail_path in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a dedicated FreeBSD 8.3 server (virtual or not, doesn't matter).

If so, then you can change the hostname by running the [`hostname(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hostname&sektion=1) command with the argument being the new hostname.  In order for the changes to be persistent across reboots, you must change the `hostname` variable in /etc/rc.conf.

However, notice that [`sendmail(8)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendmail&sektion=8) gets system hostname only when it boots, so, in order for it to notice the changes you've made, you will probably have to restart the sendmail daemon.

More details on changing your hostname here (from a simple http://www.google.com/search?q=hostname+freebsd):

http://docs.freebsd.org/doc/4.6-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/en/books/ppp-primer/system-config.html
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2006-April/119355.html